# Execute many simulations avoiding for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I am trying to simulate fitted values for changing models of different subgroups of my data, which again are based on random sampling of another subset of my original data frame (the minimal example I made up for this question ignores the random sampling etc., resulting in identical fitted values for all simulations, but that doesn't matter). I have written a dplyr-code to store the model for each group, produce new x-values for predicting fitted values, predict them etc. etc. It results in one column of fitted values, exactly as I want it. However, I would like to go through the whole process 1000x. I can of course do this with a for-loop (as done below in the example), but is there a possibility to do such a thing within a dplyr-pipe line? And maybe speed the whole process up a bit (my original data set is rather large and the for-loop takes forever)?

```
# making up data
dat <- data.frame("species" =  seq(1:20), "col_A" = runif(20, min=1000, max=2500), "col_B" = runif(20, min = 0, max = 1500), 
                  "maximum" = rep(2500, 20), "minimum" = rep(1000, 20), groups = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 4))

# functions to use with purrr
linear_mod <- function(dat) {
  lm(col_A ~ col_B, data = dat)
}

# define parametres and an empty data frame to use in the for loop
runs <- 10
fitted_sim <- data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=20,ncol=runs+1,byrow=FALSE)) #empty dataframe to contain fitted values for each alt
names(fitted_sim) <- as.factor(seq(1:runs+1))

# for-loop around my dplyr-code
for (j in 1:runs){
  simul <- dat %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    nest(data = c(col_A, col_B, species)) %>%
    mutate(model = map(data, linear_mod), # add model for every group
           sim_data = list(seq(minimum, maximum, by = 10))) %>% # define new x-values for later predictions
    unnest(sim_data) %>%
    nest(sim_data = sim_data) %>%
    mutate(fitted = map2(model, sim_data, ~predict(.x, col_B = sim_data, type = "response")), # predict values
    unnest(fitted) # unnest predicted values to save in data frame
  
  # save newly fitted values in fitted_sim data frame
  fitted_sim[,1] <- simul$groups
  fitted_sim[,1+j] <- simul$fitted
}
```

Thanks for every hint!

**EDIT:**
This is an extended example code including the random sampling described above but omitted in my first example:

```
# for-loop around my dplyr-code
for (j in 1:runs) {
  simul <- dat %>%
    group_by(groups) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(vector_column = case_when(abs(col_A) == (maximum-minimum) ~ list(col_B),
                                     sign(col_A) == 1 ~ list(dat$col_B[dat$col_B <= maximum - col_A]), # using list function to store vectors in a data.frame
                                     sign(col_A) != 1 ~ list(dat$col_B[dat$col_B >= minimum + col_A])),
           helper = !is_empty(vector_column), # in case some of the vectors are empty so it is not possible to use sample
           col_B_new = ifelse(helper, sample(vector_column, 1), NA),
           helper = NULL,
           sim_data = list(seq(minimum, maximum, by = 10))) %>% # define new x-values for later predictions
    ungroup() %>% # get rid of rowwise()
    group_by(groups) %>%
    unnest(sim_data) %>%
    nest(sim_data = sim_data) %>%
    nest(data = c(col_A, col_B, col_B_new, species)) %>%
    mutate(model = map(data, linear_mod),
           fitted = map2(model, sim_data, ~predict(.x, col_B_new = sim_data, type = "response"))) %>% # predict values
    unnest(fitted) # unnest predicted values to save in data frame
           
           # save newly fitted values in fitted_sim data frame
           fitted_sim[,1] <- simul$groups
           fitted_sim[,1+j] <- simul$fitted
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you will need from your `simul` data.frame down the road, but the individual loop elements seem to be independent of each other, so you could use `parallel:mclappy` to run them in parallel. In my example I just use `lapply`, but this is already quite a bit faster - if it helps you in any way...

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

# making up data
dat <- data.frame("species" =  seq(1:20), "col_A" = runif(20, min=1000, max=2500), "col_B" = runif(20, min = 0, max = 1500), 
                  "maximum" = rep(2500, 20), "minimum" = rep(1000, 20), groups = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 4))

# functions to use with purrr
linear_mod <- function(dat) {
    lm(col_A ~ col_B, data = dat)
}

# define parametres and an empty data frame to use in the for loop
runs <- 10
fitted_sim <- data.frame(matrix(data=NA,nrow=20,ncol=runs+1,byrow=FALSE)) #empty dataframe to contain fitted values for each alt
names(fitted_sim) <- as.factor(seq(1:runs+1))

# I just wrapped your code in a function for benchmarking
run.simul <- function(){
    for (j in 1:runs){
        simul <- dat %>%
            group_by(groups) %>%
            nest(data = c(col_A, col_B, species)) %>%
            mutate(model = map(data, linear_mod), # add model for every group
                   sim_data = list(seq(minimum, maximum, by = 10))) %>% # define new x-values for later predictions
            unnest(sim_data) %>%
            nest(sim_data = sim_data) %>%
            mutate(fitted = map2(model, sim_data, ~predict(.x, col_B = sim_data, type = "response"))) %>% # predict values
            unnest(fitted) # unnest predicted values to save in data frame
        # save newly fitted values in fitted_sim data frame
        fitted_sim[,1] <- simul$groups
        fitted_sim[,1+j] <- simul$fitted
    }
    fitted_sim
}


# my version (sorry for using `data.table`...)
Dat <- data.table(dat, key="groups")
getFits <- function(x){
    x[, fitted := predict(lm(col_A ~ col_B), .(list(seq(minimum[1], maximum[1], by = 10)))), by = groups]
    x[, .(species, groups, fitted)]
}

# get the results into a data.frame; use mclapply instead of lapply if you like
dcast(rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(runs), function(z) getFits(data.table(dat, key="groups"))), idcol = "run"), ... ~ run, value.var = "fitted")
#>     species groups        1        2        3        4        5        6
#>  1:       1      A 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621
#>  2:       2      A 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679
#>  3:       3      A 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100
#>  4:       4      A 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593
#>  5:       5      B 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408
#>  6:       6      B 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709
#>  7:       7      B 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934
#>  8:       8      B 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699
#>  9:       9      C 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187
#> 10:      10      C 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827
#> 11:      11      C 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953
#> 12:      12      C 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046
#> 13:      13      D 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615
#> 14:      14      D 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832
#> 15:      15      D 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489
#> 16:      16      D 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442
#> 17:      17      E 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359
#> 18:      18      E 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253
#> 19:      19      E 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197
#> 20:      20      E 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991
#>            7        8        9       10
#>  1: 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621
#>  2: 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679
#>  3: 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100
#>  4: 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593
#>  5: 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408
#>  6: 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709
#>  7: 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934
#>  8: 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699
#>  9: 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187
#> 10: 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827
#> 11: 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953
#> 12: 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046
#> 13: 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615
#> 14: 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832
#> 15: 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489
#> 16: 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442
#> 17: 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359
#> 18: 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253
#> 19: 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197
#> 20: 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991

run.simul()
#>    1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9
#> 1  A 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621 1767.621
#> 2  A 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679 1376.679
#> 3  A 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100 1523.100
#> 4  A 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593 1794.593
#> 5  B 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408 1272.408
#> 6  B 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709 1967.709
#> 7  B 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934 1792.934
#> 8  B 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699 2318.699
#> 9  C 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187 2017.187
#> 10 C 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827 1899.827
#> 11 C 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953 1734.953
#> 12 C 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046 1834.046
#> 13 D 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615 1797.615
#> 14 D 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832 1915.832
#> 15 D 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489 1841.489
#> 16 D 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442 1798.442
#> 17 E 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359 1641.359
#> 18 E 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253 1631.253
#> 19 E 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197 1634.197
#> 20 E 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991 1634.991
#>          10       NA
#> 1  1767.621 1767.621
#> 2  1376.679 1376.679
#> 3  1523.100 1523.100
#> 4  1794.593 1794.593
#> 5  1272.408 1272.408
#> 6  1967.709 1967.709
#> 7  1792.934 1792.934
#> 8  2318.699 2318.699
#> 9  2017.187 2017.187
#> 10 1899.827 1899.827
#> 11 1734.953 1734.953
#> 12 1834.046 1834.046
#> 13 1797.615 1797.615
#> 14 1915.832 1915.832
#> 15 1841.489 1841.489
#> 16 1798.442 1798.442
#> 17 1641.359 1641.359
#> 18 1631.253 1631.253
#> 19 1634.197 1634.197
#> 20 1634.991 1634.991

# benchmarking
microbenchmark(
    a=dcast(rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(runs), function(z) getFits(data.table(dat, key="groups"))), idcol = "run"), ... ~ run, value.var = "fitted"),
    b=run.simul(), times= 10L
    )
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#>     a  46.46851  48.65027  51.09618  49.88775  54.7177  56.2888    10  a 
#>     b 389.76893 410.57588 418.16993 415.74493 424.2042 448.4604    10   b
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is great, thanks! I'm not very familiar with data table, but I should definitely have a look into it. However, for my real data, for every round of the for-loop I randomly sample one new col_B value for each species from a list column in my data frame, can this be integrated in your code? Does data table work with list-columns?

Comment: I added an extended version of the example script to illustrate what I mean. Feel free to ignore it though, you answered my first question perfectly fine.

Comment: Unless you changed your `linear_mod` function, you did not change the models with your edit. Do you want to do `lm(col_A ~ col_B_new)`? Also, your sampling seems to be by group for `abs(col_A) == (maximum-minimum)`, but otherwise across all groups, is that intended? And yes, `data.table` deals with list columns, as seen in my `getFits` function, see the line with `.(list(seq(minimum[1], maximum[1], by = 10))`, where the `.()` wraps the list into another list to preserve the inner list in the column.

Comment: No, I did not change the models - I just wasn't sure how the integrate the additional conditions, but I figured it out now. Thanks a lot for your help!